# How to darken the colour of a font?

Tags: color

I'd like to darken the colour of that font, Garamond MT Pro, in order to make it more legible. How could I do that? This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond MT Pro}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: `color` means what you referred? If you are mentioned about normal `black`, then check the availability of `Garamond MT Pro-Black` or `UltraBlack`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Garamond MT pro-Black does not exist. In its normal color, Garamond MT pro is more grey than black. How could I make it blacker? Do I need to use xcolor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that font, but I've searched in net, and I didn't find any `grey shade`, check your version or else download again else purchase it....